# Print list elements on new line

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I wish to print the elements of an array, without commas, and on separate lines. I am writing a function for insertion sort. Though it works correctly, I am finding it tricky to print them properly. The code I've written is:

```
#!/bin/python
def insertionSort(ar):    
    newNo = ar[-1]
    for i in range(0, m-1):
        if(newNo < ar[m-i-1]):
            ar[m-i] = ar[m-i-1]
            for e in ar:
                print e,
            print '\n'
    ar[m-i-1] = newNo
    for f in ar: print f,

m = input()
ar = [int(i) for i in raw_input().strip().split()]
insertionSort(ar)
```

The output I get is:

```
2 4 6 8 8 

2 4 6 6 8 

2 4 4 6 8 

2 3 4 6 8
```

I should get the following output for the code to pass the test case:

```
2 4 6 8 8
2 4 6 6 8
2 4 4 6 8
2 3 4 6 8
```

i.e without the extra space between lines. Click [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertionsort1) for the detailed problem statement.

Comment: `print '\n'` will print two new lines... one explicit,  the other implicit...

Comment: This is the defining difference between `sys.stdout.write` and `print`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` statement appends a new line automatically, so if you use

```
print '\n'
```

You will get two new lines. So you can use an empty string as in `print ''` or the better way would be to use `print` by itself :

```
print
```

Comment: `print` by itself is fine... :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a fix -

```
def insertionSort(ar):    
newNo = ar[-1]
for i in range(0, m-1):
    if(newNo < ar[m-i-1]):
        ar[m-i] = ar[m-i-1]
        for e in ar:
            print e,
        print 
ar[m-i-1] = newNo
for f in ar: print f,

m = input()
ar = [int(i) for i in raw_input().strip().split()]
insertionSort(ar)
```

*Edit - Ok ! ^ Someone already mentioned that.*